# Chrome Constantly Accessing Code From Error 404 Page

Tags: .htaccess, google-chrome

I have a custom Error 404 page that sends me an email when someone hits it.  I'm using an .htaccess file to direct users to the 404 page if the link they click (or enter) doesn't exist.  This works fine in IE and FireFox, but for some reason when I use Chrome, the site triggers an email when it loads just about every page within the site.  I've included the .htaccess code and relevant 404 page code, though I'm not sure it'll be very useful.  I'm at a bit of a loss as to why this is happening.

.htaccess (everything I'm doing is within the 'admin' part of the site):

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.mysite.com/admin/404page.php
```

404 Page PHP:

```
<?php
    $to = "myemail@mysite.com";
    $subject = "Error Page Accessed";
    $message = "Jackel414, \r\rA user ran into the error page.";
    $from = "webadmin@mysite.com";
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>
```

Comment: Use chrome and open the developer tools and then go to network tab. Check if it doesn't get a 404 on some other resources maybe. Could be from an image or anything

Comment: @MitchDart Good thought.  I'm getting a 304 error on some of the pages - would that trip it?

Comment: As a quick follow up - this behavior still exists even though I'm not getting any errors when using the Chrome Dev Tools (I was getting a couple errors initially).